# updating NSG Rule via powershell doesnt work

Tags: powershell

I follow exactly what's on the Microsoft document but with no  luck

I'm trying to update the Priority rule from `120` to `4040`

[set-azurermnetworksecurityruleconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/set-azurermnetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azurermps-6.11.0)

code I follow:

```
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name EA-NSG-AAA -ResourceGroupName EA-RG
$nsg | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name name-02
Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name name-02 -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg -Priority 4040
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the network security group in Azure, you are only modified your local powershell object. you need to push changes to azure. sample code:

```
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName %rg_name% -Name %nsg_name%
Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg `
    -Name %rule-name% `
    -Access Allow `
    -Protocol Tcp `
    -Direction Inbound `
    -Priority 777 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix %data% `
    -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
    -DestinationPortRange 3389
$null = Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
```