# Azure updating multiple NSG rules with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, security

I'd like to update multiple NSG rules at once, based on a changing IP address list.
For example, I'd like to update rules named ftp,ssh,https (and several others).
Here is what I have so far:

```
$ips = @("10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.3", "192.168.0.0/16")
$nsgName = "Dev1-nsg"
$resourceGroupName = "myResourceGrp1"
$nsg = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsgName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "ftp" -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg -SourceAddressPrefix $ips
Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "ssh" -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg -SourceAddressPrefix $ips
Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "https" -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg -SourceAddressPrefix $ips
Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "ftp" -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "ssh" -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "https" -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
```

My issues:

1. When I run the above in Powershell, all seems fine, but when I go to the Azure nsg portal and refresh, the rules appear unchanged
2. If I'm updating many rules (say 15), what's the best way to loop through a list of rule names to update each with the IP list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We could not update the NSG rules in Azure but need to modify the local PowerShell scripts then push the change to Azure, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028450/updating-nsg-rule-via-powershell-doesnt-work).
2. To loop through a list of rule names to update each of the IP lists, you can do it like this.

   ```
    $ips = @("10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.3", "192.168.0.0/16")
    $nsgName = "ubun-a-nsg"
    $resourceGroupName = "nancy"
    $rule_names = @("NRMS-Rule-103","NRMS-Rule-104","NRMS-Rule-105")

    foreach($rule_name in $rule_names)
    {

    $nsg = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsgName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    $rule= $nsg | Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $rule_name  

    Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg `
        -Name $rule_name `
        -Access $rule.Access `
        -Protocol $rule.Protocol `
        -Direction $rule.Direction `
        -Priority $rule.Priority `
        -SourceAddressPrefix $ips `
        -SourcePortRange $rule.SourcePortRange `
        -DestinationAddressPrefix $rule.DestinationAddressPrefix `
        -DestinationPortRange $rule.DestinationPortRange `
        -Description $rule.Description

    $nsg | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup

    }
   ```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, working correctly!  The only issue I had when testing was that when including the parameter [-Description $rule.Description] it returned an error: "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Description'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again."  But if I remark that line out, everything is fine.